# Marking Qibla (i.e: Muslim's prayer direction) - ios

Tags: ios, geolocation, ios9, cllocationmanager, compass

We have a requirement to mark Qibla direction(i.e:Muslim's prayer direction. it is towards makkah). For that i have to plot North,East,West and South direction, after that i have to mark Qibla direction. I can update North,East,West and South direction by using the below code snippet:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
    {
            _compass.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f);
    }
```

Here _`compass` will be an `UIImageview` with NEWS (North,East,West and South) direction image and i want to point Qibla on this NEWS direction image. I can get lattitude and longitude of Qibla, if so will it help to mark Qibla? Or what else the solution?

Please note that; I have found some replies someway related to this topic in SO, but not clear exactly, since it all talks about some complicated mathematics calculations (like; sin,cos, tan ,etc) also talking about some unknown terms. If you can, please provide some understandable clarifications on this instead marking my question as duplicate. It will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: here you go... http://codecanyon.net/item/ios-qibla-direction-objective-c/15523429